# JQuery parse JSON return null

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

Hello I have the following JSON returned from my server side:

```
{"command":"SELECT","rowCount":1,"oid":null,"rows":[{"username":"xxxx"}],"fields":[{"name":"username","tableID":34722,"columnID":3,"dataTypeID":1043,"dataTypeSize":-1,"dataTypeModifier":204,"format":"text"}],"_parsers":[null]}
```

I'm parsing that json in javascript like this :

```
 var ParsedJSONResponse = $.parseJSON(JSONResponseFromServerSide);
```

The variable is `"ParsedJSONResponse"`  always null, my JSON is valid I checked it in JSONLint so what is going on please?

Comment: You do know that if you put the `contentType:JSON` that jQuery will parse it for you and ultimately return a a JSON object.

Comment: looks like the value is already a object not a json string so there is no need to parse it again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should parse the **String**

```
var stringJson = '{"command":"SELECT","rowCount":1,"oid":null,"rows":[{"username":"xxxx"}],"fields":[{"name":"username","tableID":34722,"columnID":3,"dataTypeID":1043,"dataTypeSize":-1,"dataTypeModifier":204,"format":"text"}],"_parsers":[null]}';  
var ParsedJSONResponse = $.parseJSON(stringJson);
```

You just have a Json (`JSONResponseFromServerSide`) and no reason to parse it.

Parsing the Json object returns `null`.

```
$.parseJSON({}); // returns `null`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct check out this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zYcKh/).

```
var JSONResponseFromServerSide = '{"command":"SELECT","rowCount":1,"oid":null,"rows":[{"username":"xxxx"}],"fields":[{"name":"username","tableID":34722,"columnID":3,"dataTypeID":1043,"dataTypeSize":-1,"dataTypeModifier":204,"format":"text"}],"_parsers":[null]}'; //it's your json string
$.parseJSON(JSONResponseFromServerSide); //nothing wrong
```

If `JSONResponseFromServerSide` is already a JavaScript object, than you don't have to do `parseJSON`